# How do I import AdminControl in WebSphere's jython?

Tags: java, websphere, jython

When running websphere's Jython I'm not able to call the AdminControl command

```
Jython 2.1 on java1.6.0 (JIT: j9jit26)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> cellName = AdminControl.getCell()
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
NameError: AdminControl
```

I haven't seen anything from IBM or elsewhere that indicates AdminControl needs to be imported so I'm not sure why the above doesn't work.

Notes

WebSphere 8.5

I'm running jython with the command:

```
"$WAS_8_5_HOME"/java/jre/bin/java.exe -jar "$WAS_8_5_HOME"/optionalLibraries/jython/jython.jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  The AdminControl object is backed by an internal type, and it is registered by wsadmin when it starts.  The only way to use it is via `wsadmin -lang jython` (possibly with `-f script.py`).